# how do I use the URL option with the maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: url, syntax, maven-jaxb2-plugin

According to the [user guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Resourceentries), I should be able to use `<url></url>` in the configuration, but that syntax is not listed in the Maven-generated [project documentation](http://static.highsource.org/mjiip/maven-jaxb2-plugin/generate-mojo.html)  Can anyone give me a working example?  Ideally, I would like to simply point to a remote resource rather than have a local one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of test projects which demonstrate this functionality:

- https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/res/
- https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-49/

ps. Please do something about your accept rate.

Comment: Thanks; I did get this to work later, though I'm not sure why it didn't at first.  With regard to my acceptance, maybe I miss the point, but I've only been accepting the answers that I actually implement.